# How to cast from Buffer[Map[String, String]] to Map[String, String]

Tags: scala

The code below throws the following error:
**type mismatch; found : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] required: Map[String,String]**

```
def getRecordsByRegExp(table: String, family: String, regExp: String): Future[Seq[SomeClass]] = {
    val scanner = hBaseClient.newScanner(table)

    scanner.setFamily(family)
    scanner.setFilter(new KeyRegexpFilter(regExp))

    scanner.nextRows.map(arrayList =>
      arrayList.flatten.map(x =>
        Record(
          table,
          new String(x.key),
          arrayList.map(keyValues =>
            keyValues.map(kv => new String(kv.qualifier) -> new String(kv.value)).toMap))))

  }
```

SomeClass definition:
**SomeClass(table: String, key: String, values: Map[String, String])**

Any tips on how to get over this?

Later edit: added all the code

Comment: what is the type of `scanner`?

Comment: do you want to construct the map over all elements in `arrayList`? If so, then you should probably call first `arrayList.flatten` before applying the `map` call where you create the `Map`. If not, then you should select the element of `arrayList` for which you want to construct the `Map`.

Comment: You might make this easier to debug for yourself by breaking this into multiple functions with type annotations.

Comment: @TillRohrmann scanner is of type org.hbase.async.Scanner. It's from the asynchbase client.

Comment: @TillRohrmann yes, I want to construct the map over all elements in arrayList. But since table and key is the same for all the elements I first tought to flatten the arraylist to get the key, and then creating the Map by calling arrayList.map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, then this could solve your problem:

```scala
scanner.nextRows.map{
  arrayList =>
    val map = arrayList.flatten.map{
      kv =>
        new String(kv.qualifier) -> new String(kv.value)
    }.toMap
    arrayList.flatten.map{
      x =>
      SomeClass(
        table,
        new String(x.key),
        map)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Till, I also made it work with:

```
scanner.nextRows.map(arrayList =>
      arrayList.flatten.map(x =>
        SomeClass(
          table,
          new String(x.key),
          Map(new String(x.qualifier) -> new String(x.value)))))
```